# SATA disk shows up on lsscsi but does not show up in lsblk

Tags: ubuntu, scsi

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 server with a Toshiba disk installed. It shows up on lsscsi:

```
# lsscsi 
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ASR8160  atc              V1.0  /dev/sda 
[0:1:8:0]    disk    ATA      TOSHIBA MQ04ABB4 JS00  -        
[0:1:9:0]    disk    ATA      TOSHIBA MQ04ABB4 JS00  -        
[0:1:10:0]   disk    ATA      TOSHIBA MQ04ABB4 JS00  -        
[0:1:11:0]   disk    ATA      TOSHIBA MQ04ABB4 JS00  -        
[0:1:12:0]   disk    ATA      CT1000MX500SSD1  M3CR  -        
[0:1:13:0]   disk    ATA      CT1000MX500SSD1  M3CR  -
```

but no block device is getting created:

```
# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  91.3M  1 loop /snap/core/8592
loop1    7:1    0  91.4M  1 loop /snap/core/8689
sda      8:0    1   931G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    1     1M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    1 223.1G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    1   708G  0 part
```

I've tried many things including running MAKEDEV, looking for any messages in dmesg, but nothing shows up.

This started happening after an update, when Ubuntu pushed out 4.15.0-91.

I'm completely stumped on this. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a SATA port multiplier?  (Could even be one built into the motherboard?)  It may be that the driver wasn't included with the new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: it was a hardware failure in the RAID array (perhaps a bad disk) that made the device not show up as a block device. Lesson learned: SCSI block devices really do show up as block devices and if they don't, it's probably the device, not the operating system.